# can we change the text on the uiSwitch

Tags: objective-c, uiswitch

can we change the text which is on the UISwitch, i.e. On & Off. i have tried the following code but its crashing

crashLog:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: '-[UISwitch setLeftLabelText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c65020'**

```
switcher = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
[switcher addTarget:self action:@selector(switchAction:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

// swit = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[switcher setCenter:CGPointMake(160.0f,260.0f)];
[switcher setLeftLabelText: @"Female"];
[switcher setRightLabelText: @"Male"];
[[switcher rightLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0f]];
[[switcher leftLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0f]];
[[switcher leftLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

cell.accessoryView = switcher;
switcher.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this : http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/
It is allowing many customization (including text)